# Should I add NetCoreapp as a dependency

Tags: .net-core

I'm trying to wrap my head around all the possible framework variations. I've seen many project.json .NET core configurations and while some of them specify .NETcoreApp as dependency:

```
{
  “version”: “1.0.0-*”,
  “buildOptions”: {
    “emitEntryPoint”: true
  },

  “dependencies”: {
    “Microsoft.NETCore.App”: {
      “type”: “platform”,
      “version”: “1.0.0”
    }
  },

  “frameworks”: {
    “netcoreapp1.0“: {
      “imports”: “dnxcore50”
    }
  }
}
```

others don't:

```
{
  “version”: “1.0.0-*”,
  “buildOptions”: {
    “emitEntryPoint”: true
  },

  “dependencies”: {
  },

  “frameworks”: {
    “netcoreapp1.0”: {
      “imports”: “dnxcore50”,
      “dependencies”: {
        “Microsoft.NETCore.App“: {
          “type”: “platform”,
          “version”: “1.0.0”
        }
      }
    },
    “net452”: {
    }
  }
```

What's the difference? When and why do I need to specify NETCore.App dependency?

By the way both samples come from [this msdn article](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/cesardelatorre/2016/06/28/running-net-core-apps-on-multiple-frameworks-and-what-the-target-framework-monikers-tfms-are-about/) and while it makes a great job expaining framework system in .NET core, it users both with and without dependency approaches interchangeably and it looks extremely confusing.

Answer (score 0):

What's the difference? `frameworks` only providing abstract layer, `dependencies` providing code